# GET request working through Python but not through Postman

Tags: python, rest, virtualenv, postman, mailman

I am trying to use the Mailman 3 REST API, but I need to call it from Spring's Rest Template in a java class, or for testing purpose from Postman.
In Python, I can call the API by:

```
>>> from httplib2 import Http
>>> headers = {
...     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencode',
...     'Authorization': 'Basic cmVzdGFkbWluOnJlc3RwYXNz',
...     }
>>> url = 'http://localhost:8001/3.0/domains'
>>> response, content = Http().request(url, 'GET', None, headers)
>>> print(response.status)
200
```

I want to make the same request, but through Postman. For that, I have used the URL "http://127.0.0.1:8001/3.0/domains". I have added 2 fields in the headers, the preview looks like:

```
GET /3.0/lists HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8001
Content-Type: application/x-form-urlencode
Authorization: Basic cmVzdGFkbWluOnJlc3RwYXNz
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

But the request status only shows "pending" and I receive no response. Mailman is running on a python virtualenv.

I am also trying to run the following command in my terminal:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/x-form-urlencoded, Authorization: Basic cmVzdGFkbWluOnJlc3RwYXNz" http://localhost:8001/3.0/domains
```

But the output is:

```
{
    "title": "401 Unauthorized",
    "description": "The REST API requires authentication"
}
```

I am stuck at this point, because I do not wish to use Mailman's Web UI postorius, but wish to call the REST API from java class. I would also like to know, if I am making a particular mistake in forming my Postman request, but how can I do the same using Spring's Rest Template.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To fix curl command, use the -H parameter seperately.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-form-urlencoded" -H "Authorization: Basic cmVzdGFkbWluOnJlc3RwYXNz" http://localhost:8001/3.0/domains
```

Comment: How can I recreate the same request in Java Spring? or Postman?

Comment: In your postman request remove `Content-Type: application/x-form-urlencode`